# CSS class specifications not being used for icon button in html5

Tags: css, html

I have a 48x48 image that I am using for an icon button.  I find that I can make it 16x16 with the following html code.

```
<button>
    <img src="48x48.png"   width="16"  height="16"/>
</button>
```

However, if instead I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.actionButton{
    width:16;
    height:16;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<button>
    <img src="48x48.png"  class="actionButton"//>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

the button size is always 48x48.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the units to your css i.e. `px` as below:

```
.actionButton{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Helllo,

you can use this :

```
<img src="48x48.png" style="width=18px; height=18px;" />
```

Or juste resize the image.